# Getting error message with using find_element_by_name from Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am using selenium to automate few tasks. My code till now just opens browser and gets username and password to fill them later but `find_element_by_name` is not working properly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\tarek\Desktop\namshi\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://my.namshi.com/")
time.sleep(5)

try:
    username = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    print(username)
except:
    print('failed')
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your HTML, it is hard to tell without it.

Comment: It is in driver.get() :)

Comment: This is an URL, which is against the rules for minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to get the password or email? Do you mean you want to click on the fields and fill them with the two queries? If so, then you need to call the click method on your username and password because the find_element_by_name function returns a web element instead of finding it (which would be way more convenient, to be honest)

Basically:

```
def log_in(email, password) -> Webelement (a class):
    username = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    username.click()
    username.send_keys(email, Keys.RETURN)
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    password.click()
    password.send_keys(password, Keys.RETURN)

try:
    log_in()

except:
    print('failed')
```

Comment: I need to fill them with my email and password.

Comment: In that case, you don't need to print anything. A simple send_keys('email', Keys.Return) Like so:  search.send_keys(query, Keys.RETURN) after clicking each element. I forgot to mention that, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three elements with name email, I have tried this XPath:

```
//*[@name='email']
```

Your element is the second one I guess:

```
(//input[@name='email'])[2]
```